# Why yellow/white backgrounds mess up my image?

Tags: html, css, image, photoshop

I am using a logo image I designed on a image-background. Whenever background contains yellow/white -ish colors my logo gets red-ish pixels out of nowhere.

[image]

Code here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk9zc6gy/1/)

```html
<div style="background-color:black;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DrNSqdq/logostern.png" height="100px">
</div>
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DrNSqdq/logostern.png" height="100px">
</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DrNSqdq/logostern.png" height="100px">
</div>
<div style="background-color:white;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DrNSqdq/logostern.png" height="100px">
</div>
<div style="background:url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61IxMLc8xHL._SX425_.jpg');">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DrNSqdq/logostern.png" height="100px">
</div>
```

On black/red background everything looks fine. On white/yellow a background strange pixels of red appears.

Did I did something wrong saving the image or what is going on here?

EDIT: Thank you for answers everyone. The problem was indeed with my computer. The problem was only on Chrome, on Mozilla everything looked fine. It must be a problem with my graphics drivers.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. It is most certainly a problem with the graphics card, the driver or the compositing of OS. In what browser (and version)  and on what system does this happen?

Comment: Any particular reason why you won't tell what OS and which browser this happens in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the issue of your system graphic processor or browser.
Because at my end I can see it fine.[image: it is the correct view]